# Perimeter of Kerr's event horizon

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

We can compute the "proper circumference" of the Schwarzschild event horizon integrating its line element along its perimeter at a fixed $t$. This would be the minimum length of a rope that goes arround the black hole measured by the static observers that mantain it just above the horizon. (I am using $\tau=2\pi$).

$$C_S = \int_0^\tau \sqrt{g_{\phi\phi}}d\phi = 2\tau M$$

If I make the same calculation in the equator of the Kerr metric I obtain the same result for all values of the rotation parameter $a$. However, now the rope is inside the ergosphere, so it can't be stationary. How can I obtain the minimum length of the rope in this case?

I think the answer could be obtained using the zero angular momentum observers (ZAMOs), but I'm not even sure how to use them. Could I just Lorentz contract the perimeter? Is the question even well defined? I arrived at it trying to measure some distances around the black hole, inside the ergosphere this problem arises.

Comment: Even in special relativity, the analogous question is quite deep: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox

Comment: @Andrew Totally agree. A key idea that will keep coming up if OP looks further into the SR case is that rotating observers have trouble establishing any global notion of simultaneity, thus even if you can fabricate some definition of length, its "physicality" may be a bit disappointing.

Comment: @Integralfan It is possible to obtain a notion of global simultaneity on the rotating perimeter, but the clockwise speed of light will be different to the anti-clockwise speed of light and they will have to use an average two way speed of light that is equal to c. Such clocks on the perimeter can be synchronised by using a master clock in the centre and scaling down the frequency of its signals. You can also fabricate a definition of length, but the rotating observers will measure the perimeter to be longer than the perimeter measured by inertial observers. Try it and see :-)

Comment: @ KDP Will think about this; so one is essentially altering usual Einstein synchronization axioms by axiomatically working in the Sagnac effect?

Comment: @Integralfan Yes, exactly. Having different one way speeds of light is not such a big problem, when you consider we cant even measure the one way speed of light in an inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizon is a *null hypersurface*, the metric induced on it is degenerate, so it does not matter how you define hypersurface $t=\mathrm {const}$,   circumference of the equator would not change.

Comment: Then that would mean the original $C_S$ answer is correct no matter how fast the rope spins (just) above the Kerr equator?

Comment: You cannot spin the rope arbitrarily fast as it approaches closer to the surface of event horizon. From the viewpoint of asymptotic observer lightcones become narrower as they approach the horizon so there would be only one possible $d\phi/dt$ ($t$ is coordinate time) on the horizon.

Comment: I thought that was only a problem of the BL coordinates and that there could be different speeds measured by the asymptotic observer. That is still true in other parts of the ergosphere, but that's a different question. Thanks!